# Jackson MismatchedInputException : no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value

Tags: jackson, resttemplate, jackson-dataformat-xml

I use RestTemplate.exchange in my Spring Boot app to GET this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<advertisers current_page="1" per_page="10" total_pages="1" total_entries="1">
  <advertiser>
    <id>1057343</id>
    <name>SOME ADVERTISER</name>
    <status>ACTIVE</status>
    <created_at>2021-10-12T09:06:12Z</created_at>
    <updated_at>2022-04-08T13:36:50Z</updated_at>
  </advertiser>
</advertisers>
```

Advertisers.java:

```
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Advertisers {
    List<Advertiser> advertiser;
}
```

Advertiser.java:

```
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Advertiser {
    String id;
    String name;
    String status;
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class fr.canalplus.tvseg.models.freewheel.entities.Advertisers] and content type [application/xml;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `fr.canalplus.tvseg.models.freewheel.entities.Advertiser` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1057343'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `fr.canalplus.tvseg.models.freewheel.entities.Advertiser` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1057343')
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 4, column: 16] (through reference chain: fr.canalplus.tvseg.models.freewheel.entities.Advertisers["advertiser"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1020)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:778)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
    at fr.canalplus.tvseg.services.FreeWheelService.exchange(FreeWheelService.java:102)
    at fr.canalplus.tvseg.services.FreeWheelService.getCreativeAdvertiser(FreeWheelService.java:154)
    at fr.canalplus.tvseg.controllers.TestController.test(TestController.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `fr.canalplus.tvseg.models.freewheel.entities.Advertiser` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1057343'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `fr.canalplus.tvseg.models.freewheel.entities.Advertiser` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1057343')
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 4, column: 16] (through reference chain: fr.canalplus.tvseg.models.freewheel.entities.Advertisers["advertiser"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:387)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:342)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:105)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `fr.canalplus.tvseg.models.freewheel.entities.Advertiser` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1057343')
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 4, column: 16] (through reference chain: fr.canalplus.tvseg.models.freewheel.entities.Advertisers["advertiser"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1455)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1081)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1408)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:176)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:166)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:290)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:249)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:371)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:164)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4526)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3521)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:376)
    ... 60 more
```

I don't understand why the id '1057343' can't be deserialize.

Can you help please? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception thrown by Jackson is really quite misleading.

You need to tell Jackson that your sequence of
`<advertiser> ...</advertiser>` elements is *not* wrapped
by an additional XML element.
You do this in your `Advertisers` class
by annotating the `List<Advertiser>` property with

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
```

See also the [javadoc of `JacksonXmlElementWrapper.useWrapping`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html#useWrapping()).